# What would cause the Data Disks attached to an Azure Virtual Machine to suddenly become unattached?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk

I have been running two Azure Windows 2016 VM's, running SQL Server 2017, in a Failover Cluster setup.

For 3 weeks these have been running fine.  But the last two days the Data Disk (connected as 'F:' where the SQL Data is stored) gets inexplicably unattached.

Thus the SQL Servers stop working, the failover is rendered pointless as it fails over to the other server which is also not working.

What would cause a Data Disk to detach like this?

Rebooting the VM's fixing the issue, thankfully. And all the data remains intact, but this can happen out of office hours and is really not ideal.

Comment: check windows event logs? i think the fact that they get reattached on reboot should indicate this is not a platform issue

Comment: There was an intermittent outage yesterday. Perhaps your disk-detach issue is related?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMakogon. This issue occurred before the outage, but appreciate you taking time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation the Disk wasn't detach, it sound like is was taken offline on the OS level.

Unfortunately this is a common thing for SQL Cluster to do when the disk is exhausted performance wise.

Make sure you are following Microsoft's Performance guidelines for SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance

If you are following performance guidelines and still getting the issue then you need a support request to investigate performance on platform side.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Sorry for the delay in replying.  I have gone through your link and seems I am following the guidelines.  I am checking that we are not overloading the disks somehow, but have also submitted a ticket with Azure.  It has not happened since this day, so am hoping it was a temporary blip.